# Exclude a device from seeing the mobile version in an MVC 4 mobile application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I would like the iPad to see the desktop view of the website and not access the .mobile.cshtml version of the site.

Is there any documentation on how to do this?

Comment: Detect the width of the browser window, I suppose.

Comment: Use media query  or  if the user agent string is unique, create a iPad layout file. See my tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features  -- let me know if you solve this and I'll update my tutorial

Comment: I don't need this solved anymore, looking with an emulator at localhost shows the mobile version but the live website is correctly showing the website version... I have since tested on an actual iPad and it is correct too.